# VS Code: change letter spacing (tracking/kerning)

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I change the horizontal letter spacing in VS Code?

I'd like to reduce it a little, in other words, I want to change this:

[image: before]

to this:

[image]

Comment: Other than changing the font to something more condensed, I would doubt that any code editor has that kind of control over kerning.

Comment: It's an open issue right now. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18715. If you absolutely must have it now, you can tinker with the CSS in the electron app, I think `workbench.main.css` is the right place.

Comment: this is called tracking, not kerning. kerning is the tuning of specific letter pairs, tracking is the overall horizontal interletter spacing

Comment: Thanks @awelotta, I've added "tracking" to the title. I'm opting to keep "kerning" in the title as well, since I think it might be a common (if incorrect) way of referring to tracking (it was the keyword I googled for first). This way the question is easier to find.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can adjust the "editor.letterSpacing" setting to change letter spacing. For example, I'm setting it to a small negative value to tighten up the letter spacing ever so slightly:

```
{
    "editor.letterSpacing": -0.15
}
```

Comment: any way to do this for the entire UI? adding spacing allows to read without glasses!

Comment: If anyone is looking to change the letter spacing for the integrated terminal, the setting is `terminal.integrated.letterSpacing`.

Comment: @khaledh Thanks, I was wondering why `terminal.letterSpacing` wasn't working

Answer (score 2):

I actually just went the opposite way after installing the wonderful [Victor Mono font](https://rubjo.github.io/victor-mono/) which I found to be too narrow and wanted to expand the kerning.

I was able to set this by simply searching in the User Settings (CTRL+SHIFT+P) for `spacing` and there are two separate boxes that were set to `0` for terminal and editor. You can change the value and see it update live, which is really cool.

This is as of my current version of VS Code `1.39.2` on Mac OS Mojave.

I set my terminal to `1` and the editor to `0.7` and it looks amazing now and all is right with the world.