# My terminal is acting weird in vs-code, there is a space between every character?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've used vscode for some time, and I have never experienced this, but suddenly the integrated terminal started acting weird. There is a space between every letter, and the cursor appears one line above the writing position. This screenshot should clarify:
[image]

I've tried to change my terminal settings, and after changing an arbitrary terminal setting it immediately goes back to normal. But when I create a new terminal it's formatted wrongly, and I have to change a terminal setting to fix it. Do you know what's going on?

Comment: Try to edit the space size like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931964/vs-code-change-letter-spacing-kerning

Comment: This is only affecting my terminal, and I haven't changed my font.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/67910121/11107541

Comment: fyi: VS Code 1.86 recently had a regression causing behaviour like this, but it got fixed. see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/194156

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [another GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120004), it looks like this is a known bug and is temporarily resolved by resizing the dimensions of the integrated terminal window.

Comment: It bugs me that this issue still exists and yet the linked GitHub issue is **closed**.  I don't know what to do about that.

Comment: I did `Terminal`->`new Terminal` and problem solved.

Comment: still exist in 2024!

Answer (score 5):

In my case the problem was coming from a missing set of fonts (Cascadia Code PL)
After installing them, everything was working fine.

Comment: Same here, it was the missing Fira code font.

Comment: Great answer, full day struggling with it till I found this, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings and search for font-family and make sure you are using Monospace fonts (a font where each character occupies the same amount of space on a horizontal line of text)

To check if a font is monospace just google `'is font_name monospace ?'` Or see the `[list] [1]` of monospace fonts.

Note fonts are loaded as per the order in the array `['first_font', 'second_font', 'third_font',.....]`
So if 1st font is not available second will be loaded

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure the spelling of your *font Family* is spelt right

Comment: For me, resizing didn't work, but editing the font family fixed it. (I edited it back to its original value and it continued working, so it wasn't a spelling issue.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @TechSolomon, @herve and @Emilio's answers, I've found the issue arises often when using multiple integrated VS Code terminals.

The fix that worked for me without quitting your terminal was to open `Settings` and go `Terminal > Integrated: Font Family`, and replace the fonts in the list with something safe like `monospace`. This forces the terminals to re-render their text:

```
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'Source code pro', 'Fira Code', Consolas, monospace"
>>>
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "monospace"
```

Put back your fonts of choice and it should re-render them correctly.

Answer (score -1):

It may resolve by reset the setting of **font family** in vs code.
Be careful at a time of choose spelling of *font family* because it can create problem.

Comment: This doesn't add much to the existing answer, I think.

Answer (score -3):

**Just resize the terminal in vscode , it will solve the problem.**

Comment: This doesn't add much to the existing answer, I think.