# vscode terminal is acting weired, there is a spce between each character, cursor is not at the right position

Tags: powershell, command-prompt, visual-studio-code

I use vscode daily, today integrated terminal started acting weird. There is a space between every letter, and the cursor is not at the right position. See the following screenshot:

[image]

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I would check the font setting, and if that doesn't reveal anything, check the codepage setting, though I don't know where you would see or change codepage for the terminal.

Comment: I have the same problem :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My terminal is acting weird in vs-code, there is a space between every character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66910984/my-terminal-is-acting-weird-in-vs-code-there-is-a-space-between-every-character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.

Just resize the terminal in vscode , it will solve the problem.