# VS Code Terminal Gone Weird

Tags: visual-studio-code

For some reason, all of the sudden, my terminal window in VS Code has gone "weird".  Sorry for being so technical.  :-)
Here's screen grab of what it looks like. Any thoughts on why this started happening and how to fix it?  I can go to settings and change the cursor style to anything other than what it currently is, it resets to look like a typical CMD window.  But, if I restart VS Code, the issue occurs again.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

[VS Code Terminal Window Gone Wonky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGUFp.png)

Comment: What is your OS?  This is a known issue and I believe already fixed in Insiders.  The next stable will be out later this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120004 if you are using macOS or linux.  It is a known issue which may already be fixed.  There are a couple of proposed user fixes to try until the new Stable build is out later this week.

See the issue for more info but you could try setting your

`terminal.integrated.letterSp[acing` to `1` to see if that fixes it for you in the meantime.

Comment: That did it!  I am using Windows, but when I went to the settings (terminal.integrate.letterSP), it was set to 0.  When I set it to 1, it set properly.  More importantly, when I closed and re-opened VS Code, the changes remained.

Thanks!!!!