# Weird font layout in vsCode terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

For some reason when I opened up my vsCode terminal today the font and spacing was different and I am not sure to restore it back to the default settings

[image]

I have tried to resize the terminal window which does not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My terminal is acting weird in vs-code, there is a space between every character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66910984/my-terminal-is-acting-weird-in-vs-code-there-is-a-space-between-every-character)

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I had my font-family wrong

I had this
`,Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace`

Instead of this
`Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace`

The extra comma at the front made all the difference