# Strange spacing in JUnit Test Results view in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, junit

[image]

This is an unmanaged folder project, and I'm running JUnit tests from the test view.
The tests work and succeed, and produce no console output.  Anybody know where the weird spacing is coming from?  It doesn't seem to be deterministic - the spaces are in different places on each run.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem - found a workaround.
Press Ctrl + '+' to zoom and Ctrl + '-' to zoom out again.

[My terminal is acting weird in vs-code, there is a space between every character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66910984/my-terminal-is-acting-weird-in-vs-code-there-is-a-space-between-every-character)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).