# How to change letter spacing VS code terminal?

Tags: command-line-interface

I want to change letter spacing in vscode terminal, how to do that, thank you

[This is example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yolb.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code: change letter spacing (kerning)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931964/vs-code-change-letter-spacing-kerning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try add this
`{"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "monospace"}`
to your `setting.json` , it work for me

Answer (score 1):

you can edit https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/appearance

in your config for VSCode search for:

`terminal.integrated.letterSpacing`

[image]

Comment: in my setting, letter spacing is 0, but still have space

Comment: @Programmer did you restart VSCode after making the change?