# VS Code Terminal unreadable. Not a fontFamily issue

Tags: visual-studio-code

I decided to write this after reading countless similar questions that included recommended fixes that didn't work for me.  After going through every terminal setting, I found my answer.  I've never seen it written in any of the others, so consider this a public service announcement.

I use both the standard VS Code and the insider's edition.  This problem was specific to the standard version. Yes, I know about monospace.  Yes, I know about terminal.integrated.fontFamily.  This was something different.

Here's what I was looking at:
[image: Disaster]
To get all the terminal-related settings up, I entered this in the command pallet:
`"@feature:terminal"`

I then changed the default value of this setting from 0 to 5: `Terminal>Integrated: Letter Spacing`

That single setting fixed the font issue on my integrated terminal.
[image: Fixed]

Comment: Please do not include the answer in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change letter spacing VS code terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74638316/how-to-change-letter-spacing-vs-code-terminal)