# why is font in intellij idea differs from vscode?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, fonts

I'm wondering why the same JetBrains Mono font is different in different IDEs

Comment: note: if you want to change letter spacing in VS Code, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/42931964/11107541

Comment: put quote chars around `Jetbrains Mono` like the `Courier New`, you write a CSS style in VSC

Answer (score 2):

JetBrains uses Java Runtime Font Rendering. VS Code for Windows uses Windows native font rendering. The most significant difference is the default letter spacing. In many editors, this setting is already configurable. Upvote related ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-5247 to support letter spacing configuration in IntelliJ platform.